# Trying to wrap my head around message flow with django channels

Tags: django, python-asyncio, django-channels

I'm trying to wrap my head around Django channels. I'm completely new to async programming and I'm trying to understand why my code behaves like this.

I'm currently building an app using Django channels, currently using the in memory channel layer in settings.py:

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels.layers.InMemoryChannelLayer"
    }
}
```

I'm trying to start a long running task via a websocket and want the consumer to send periodic updates to the client.

Example code:

```
import time
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
from channels.generic.websocket import JsonWebsocketConsumer

class Consumer(JsonWebsocketConsumer):

    def connect(self):
        print("connected to consumer")
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
            f'consumer_group',
            self.channel_name
        )
        self.accept()

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)(
            'consumer_group',
            self.channel_name
        )
        self.close()

    def long_running_thing(self, event):

        for i in range(5):
            time.sleep(0.2)
            async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
                'consumer_group',
                {
                    "type": "log.progress",
                    "data": i
                }
            )
            print("long_running_thing", i)

    def log_progress(self, event):
        print("log_progress", event['data'])

    def receive_json(self, content, **kwargs):
        print(f"Received event: {content}")
        if content['action'] == "start_long_running_thing":
            async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
                'consumer_group',
                {
                    "type": "long.running.thing",
                    "data": content['data']
                }
            )
```

The consumer starts `long_running_thing` once it receives the right action. The calls to `log_progress` however happen *after* `long_running_thing` has completed.

Output:

```
Received event: {'action': 'start_long_running_thing', 'data': {}}
long_running_thing 0
long_running_thing 1
long_running_thing 2
long_running_thing 3
long_running_thing 4
log_progress 0
log_progress 1
log_progress 2
log_progress 3
log_progress 4
```

Could someone explain to me why it is like that and how I'm able to log the progress correclty?

*Edit*: added `routing.py` and the JavaScript part.

```
from django.urls import re_path

from sockets import consumers

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'$', consumers.Consumer),
]
```

I'm currently using vue.js with vue-native-websocket,this is the relevant part on the frontend.

```
const actions = {
  startLongRunningThing(context){
    const message = {
      action: "start_long_running_thing",
      data: {}
    }
    Vue.prototype.$socket.send(JSON.stringify(message))
}
```

Comment: Can you add the `routing` and the `javascript` portion where you make that call?

Comment: @drec4s done, thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 0):

I'm also starting with async programming, but I suggest you to use instead the [AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/consumers.html#asyncwebsocketconsumer), and, after sending the events over the [channel_layer](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/channel_layers.html), use the `send_json` function:

```
import asyncio
import json
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer


class Consumer(AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer):

    async def connect(self):
        print("connected to consumer")
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            f'consumer_group',
            self.channel_name
        )
        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            'consumer_group',
            self.channel_name
        )
        await self.close()

    async def task(self):
        for i in range(5):
            print("long_running_thing: ", i)
            await asyncio.sleep(i)
            print("log_progress: ", i)
            await self.send_json({
                'log_progress': i
            })

    async def long_running_thing(self, event):
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        task = loop.create_task(self.task())
        await task


    async def receive_json(self, content, **kwargs):
        print(f"Received event: {content}")
        if content['action'] == "start_long_running_thing":
            await self.channel_layer.group_send(
                'consumer_group',
                {
                    "type": "long.running.thing",
                    "data": content['data']
                }
            )
```

Output:

```
INFO: ('127.0.0.1', ) - "WebSocket /" [accepted]
Received event: {'action': 'start_long_running_thing', 'data': {}}
long_running_thing:  0
log_progress:  0
long_running_thing:  1
log_progress:  1
long_running_thing:  2
log_progress:  2
long_running_thing:  3
log_progress:  3
long_running_thing:  4
log_progress:  4
```

Comment: this works because your `task` calls `send_json` directly. I need the event go over the channel layer :/

Comment: Not sure I follow. The `send_json` method sends the data over the channel layer. Every user subscribed to the `group` receives the message from the `send_json` method.

Comment: More on this [here](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/channel_layers.html)

Comment: take a look at my example: `long_running_thing` sends a message over the `channel_layer` using the `group_send` function with `log.progress` as a type for which `log_progress` is a listener.